# OAuth Endpoint Type in WSO2 API

Tags: wso2

I have a secured API with OAuth and I have no other authorization mechanism (Basic Auth/ Digest Auth).

Based on article https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/design-api/endpoints/endpoint-types/:
*"You cannot call backend services secured with OAuth through APIs created in the API Publisher. At the moment, you can call only services secured with username/password (Basic Auth/ Digest Auth)."*

Are there any plans to implement this feature in WSO2?

Answer (score 1):

Although this feature is not available OOB, you can get this done via a mediation extension. Please check this article [1] where it explains on how to invoke a backend that is secured by OAuth2.

Currently, this feature is under development and will be adding to the product in the next release.

[1] - https://medium.com/@menakajayawardena/wso2-how-to-using-oauth2-protected-back-ends-with-api-manager-5d7e234c61c

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've did all steps as described in artical but with no luck.I always have an error: <ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
  <ams:code>900901</ams:code>
  <ams:message>Invalid Credentials</ams:message>
  <ams:description>Invalid JWT token. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials</ams:description>
</ams:fault>. But the API key is working when I use Postman to call my API. Do you have ideas why it can't be authorized by WSO2?

Comment: Are you trying this in API manager v3.1.0? Can u invoke other APIs without any issue?